# Kotlin Retrofit Error: "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was string"

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I am working on an android project. I use Kotlin and I'm just learning it. I want to use Retrofit 2 for my request. I use Java this method and it is done.

I want to register user my database. When I use my function, return success for web services but it saves the empty value and I take this error: "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT was string at line 3 column 1 path$". How we can solve this problem? Actually, I read and implementing other solutions but they don't work for me.

My API:

```
@POST("userregister.php")
fun doRegister(
    @Body signupRequest: SignupRequest
): Call<SignupResponse> // body data
```

My API Service:

```
 object ApiServiceWithOutRX  {

    private const val BASE_URL = "https://alperenyukselaltug.com/api/TurkAi/"

    var gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create()

    fun ApiCall() = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .client(ApiWorker.client)
        .build()
        .create(APIListWithOutRX::class.java)!!
}
```

And my register function:

```
val email = editTextMail!!.text.toString().trim()
    val password = editTextPassword!!.text.toString().trim()

    val json = JSONObject()
    json.put("UserEmail", email)
    json.put("UserPassword", password)
    json.put("UserProfilePicture", "")

    ApiServiceWithOutRX.ApiCall().doRegister(
        SignupRequest(
            email,
            password,
            ""
        )
    ).enqueue(object : Callback<SignupResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<SignupResponse>,
            response: Response<SignupResponse>
        ) {

            Log.d("Response::::", response.body().toString())
            val loginResponse: SignupResponse
            loginResponse = response.body()!!
            if (loginResponse.status) {
                finish()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, response.body()!!.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<SignupResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    })
```

My Model:

```
data class User(
    @SerializedName("UserEmail")
    val UserEmail: String?,
    @SerializedName("UserPassword")
    val UserPassword: String?,
    @SerializedName("UserProfilePicture")
    val UserProfilePicture: String?
)

class SignupResponse(val status: Boolean, val message:String, val data: User)
class SignupRequest(@SerializedName("UserEmail") var UserEmail: String,
                    @SerializedName("UserPassword") var UserPassword: String,
                    @SerializedName("UserProfilePicture") var UserProfilePicture: String)
```

Comment: Your server code in userregister.php responses status 200 with empty body and text/html content type but android expects SignupResponse object with fields: status, message and data. It's normal situation?

Comment: When I create a user; I get see my values and return status 200. You are right, it is not normal situation. How set in my field?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem. First, I return my server side a string with PHP in echo. I return a string value. So I change my @Post like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("userregister.php")
fun doRegister(
    @Field("UserEmail") UserEmail:String,
    @Field("UserPassword") UserPassword:String,
    @Field("UserProfilePicture") UserProfilePicture:String
):Call<String>
```